# Sorting files into folders, according to a part of filename using Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file, cmd

I have around 12,000 **.jpg** files in a data-set folder in **G:\train** with names such as

*0002_c1s1_000451_03.jpg, 0002_c1s1_000551_01.jpg...*

up to

*...1500_c6s3_086542_02.jpg , 1500_c6s3_086567_01.jpg*

I want to move them to new folders with their initial filename such as *0002, 0005, 0007,... 1496, 1500*

What I need is a Windows batch file to create new folders & move files quickly without a hassle. I've tried few other answers to no avail.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You were probably really close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do, as a .cmd/.bat script file:

```
@rem The DEBUG_RUN variable enables a step-by-step mode, it will cause the 
@rem script to pause after processing every file. Remove the DEBUG_RUN (and 
@rem the pause instruction) when you are confident it does what you want,
@rem restart the script and enjoy :-)

:main
@setlocal
    @set DEBUG_RUN=1
    @pushd "G:\train"
        @for %%f in (*.jpg) do @(
            call :mvToSubDir "%%~nxf"
            if defined DEBUG_RUN pause
        )
    @popd
    @pause
@endlocal
@goto:eof

:mvToSubDir
    @set fn=%~1
    @set dn=%fn:~0,4%
    @if not exist "%dn%" mkdir "%dn%"
    move "%fn%" "%dn%"
@goto:eof
```

Comment: It says `The system cannot find the file *.jpg.` Shouldn't there be a token or something. My knowledge is really limited. Can u help?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I think there is no "/f" after the "for" command.
It's the most basic "for" call actuall.
       FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command

Comment: Please note that this works because all your directories are prefixed by 4 characters long (cf. dirname=%filename:~0,4%), if they were variable length, we'd have to be more clever.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a series of for loops to accomplish this

for /l %%f in (1,1,12000) do (
mkdir %%f
for %%d in (c:\sourcedir) do (
move %%d %%f
)
)

i didn't fully understand how you wanted to sort them but i hope this helps. You can use the "for /?" command and feel free to ask for more help if this isn't enough. I wish you luck with your endeavors.